# How to count each instance where a certain product was sold after a different product? SQL or DAX

Tags: sql, count, dax

Sorry if the title seems confusing, it was the best I could come up with.

I can work with both excel(Dax since its a power query) and sql:

I have a situation where there are two product types being purchased, Type_A and Type_B.

I want to calculate a count of how many unique Loc_ID have purchased a "Type_A" Product type, AFTER purchasing a "Type_B" Product type.

From my example there are a total of 3 unique Loc_ID which would fall in this filter: Loc_01, Loc_02, and Loc_04

Any help is greatly appreciated [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (it works good if each loc_id purchased both type of products as in your example.

```
select count(*)
from
(select loc_id , max(date_purchased) dt
from table t where product_type = 'type_a'
group by loc_id) a,
(select loc_id , max(date_purchased) dt
from table t where product_type = 'type_b'
group by loc_id) b
where a.loc_id=b.loc_id and a.dt>b.dt;
```

Comment: I think this might do the trick. What would happen if a certain loc_id did NOT purchase both type of products? It would just not include that in the results?

Comment: It would ignore them. To include those that purchased either product, simply replace the "and" in the last line with the word "or"

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Comment: @james5 Hey, one last question: If i wanted to see all instances of times where type_A was purchased after Type_B product, how would I go about doing that? Remove the Max and grouping on Loc_ID?

Comment: Nvm, i figured it out. Thanks again all

Answer (score 1):

This will work even if certain `loc_id` did not purchase both type of `products`

Try this:-

```
Select count(a.loc_id) as cnt_locations
from
your_table_name a
inner join
(
    Select a.loc_id,b.date_purchased,b.Product_type 
    from
    (
    Select loc_id, min(date_purchased) as date_purchased 
    from
    your_table_name 
    group by loc_id
    ) a
    inner join
    your_table_name b
    on a.loc_id=b.loc_id and a.date_purchased =b.date_purchased 
    where Product_type ='Type_B'
) b
on
a.loc_id=b.loc_id 
where a.date_purchased >b.date_purchased and a.Product_type ='Type_A'
```

Comment: I appreciate your input.